# Creating a dictionary from a given text file (python)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, dictionary, split, strip

I need to create a dictionary from a file that I was given. The file, named student_data.txt reads:

```
Joy - 100  
Rita - 90  
John - 80  
Sheena - 100  
Smith - 100  
Karl - 90  
Andrew - 100  
Klara - 100  
Sarah - 90  
Amy - 80  
Sandy - 100
```

I want to create a dictionary using the student's name as the key and the score as the value.

Here's what I've tried:

```
myDictionary = {}  
myFile = open("student_data.txt", 'r')  
for line in myFile:  
    key, value = line.strip().split('-')  
    myDictionary[key.strip()] = value.strip()
```

When I compile and run this I get an error saying "ValueError: Needs more than 1 value to unpack."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is an empty line in your file. Try printing the line you read before you the `split` to get a clue:

```
myDictionary = {}  
myFile = open("a.txt", 'r')  
for line in myFile:
    fields = line.strip().split('-')
    if len(fields) == 2:
        myDictionary[fields[0].strip()] = fields[1].strip()
print(myDictionary)
```

Fixed the code to handle an empty line - we check to see that we captured exactly 2 fields and only update the dictionary if this is the case.

Another approach is to check the line for content:

```
myDictionary = {}  
myFile = open("a.txt", 'r')  
for line in myFile:
    if line.isspace():
        continue
    key, value = line.strip().split('-')
    myDictionary[key.strip()] = value.strip()
print (myDictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. Are you sure there aren't any blank lines in the file?

Try this:

```
for line in myFile:
    pair = line.split('-')
    myDictionary[pair[0].strip()] = pair[1].strip()
```

If it fails, you know you have blank lines in the file somewhere that you have to account for.

Comment: I got an error saying the list index was out of range.

Comment: Then you have a blank line somewhere in your file

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would fix this issue?

Comment: Either delete the empty lines from the file or check to make sure the line isn't blank before processing it.